# Plot GeoIP data on a World Map

Tags: python, geolocation, maps, plot

I need a library (preferably written in Python) which is able to take a series of IP addresses (or geographic coordinates) and plots them on a World Map.

I already found [this one](http://gsl-nagoya-u.net/appendix/software/worldmap/), but it outputs data as a .svg file and it's simply unable to cope with large data sets.

Please note that I need something which can be downloaded and run locally, so no data uploading to 3rd party web services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) in [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) for the plotting.

It can do all sorts of [projections](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapsetup.html) (don't mind the ugly default colours).  And you have good control over what/how you plot.  You can even use [NASA Blue Marble imagery](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html).  And of course, you can plot markers, lines, etc on the map [using the plot command](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html).

I haven't put huge datasets through it, but being that it is a part of Matplotlib I suspect it will do well.

If I remember right, despite being part of the library, by default it doesn't ship with Matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can fetch the locations and write some code to put them on a map, but there's also an easier way to do this.

You can use IPInfo's free [Map IPs](http://ipinfo.io/map) tool, which will create an interactive map of IP addresses. Here's an example for [AWS IP Ranges](https://ipinfo.io/map/7c9e3031-ff5a-4769-bdd2-3506831d63a0).

[image: map ips tool preview]

You can either copy/paste the IPs or use the tool via cURL. It will process up to 500K IPs.

```sh
$ cat ipList | curl -XPOST --data-binary @- "ipinfo.io/map?cli=1"
```

**Disclaimer**: I work at IPInfo.

Comment: ipinfo.io is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 2):

The google maps API can support all of the above if you would be willing to set up a local web environment for testing.  There is a wrapper around the API for Python called [pymaps](http://code.google.com/p/pymaps/).

The API documentation has an example on how to use Google's geocoder to plot points on a map given a particular input address:

[Google Maps API Example: Simple Geocoding](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=5&ved=0CB0QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgmaps-samples.googlecode.com%2Fsvn%2Ftrunk%2Fgeocoder%2Fsinglegeocode.html&rct=j&q=google+maps+geocoder+example&ei=cbvVSq16lKQwtdC0lQM&usg=AFQjCNHzLhF0T07OOBamhHY-cPo_puj2eg)

Comment: From what I understand, pymaps is just a wrapper to make using Google Maps easier. However, I want to run this completely offline, without sending any data outside (to Google for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [`mapsplotlib`](https://github.com/tcassou/mapsplotlib).

### Installation

ONLY PYTHON 2.7!

```
$ pip install mapsplotlib
$ pip install pandas
```

You'll then need to have a Google Static Maps API key, go to https://console.developers.google.com

### Usage

```
import pandas as pd
from mapsplotlib import mapsplot as mplt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

mplt.register_api_key('your_google_api_key_here')
mplt.density_plot(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])
```

### Example output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [`gmplot`](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot).

Simply install it with

```
pip install gmplot
```

It is *extremely* easy to use. All you have to do is plug in the longitude and latitude values and `gmplot` will put out a map in html-form.

Here's a minimal example. Let `lat_values` and `lon_values` be lists of latitude and longitude values.

```
from gmplot import gmplot
import numpy as np

center_lat = np.mean(lat_values)
center_lon = np.mean(lon_values)
zoom = 15

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(center_lat, center_lon, zoom) 
gmap.scatter(lat_values, lon_values)
gmap.draw('my_map.html')
```

That's it! Of course, you can tune parameters to enhance the visuals. See the [crash course here](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot).