# Python library for animated map visualization

Tags: python, plot, geolocation, maps, visualization

I want to visualize track on geographic map. I don't need thousands of layers, 3d and other GIS functionality. I just want to visualize my `(latitude, longitude, altitude, time)` tuples on map background as simple as possible. Animation should also be supported.

Could anyone recommend good Python library?

Comment: Let's take a look at: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565555/plot-geoip-data-on-a-world-map)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's something called [basemap](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/index.html) which is an addon for matplotlib to do maps.

See the [gallery](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/users/examples.html) or [cookbook example](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Maps).

Matplotlib has it's own [animation support](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) and I don't know any reason it shouldn't work with basemap (although as that page notes, it's not the fastest thing around).

Answer (score 6):

There is a YouTube video series which covers basemap and matplotlib called 'Geographical Plotting with Python' posted by Sentdex.

Part 1 - 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6gvtfQHJUs

Incidentally he has a number of other interesting Python projects on his channel: 
http://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex